# Can you sum strings in mysql?

Tags: mysql

mysql 5.5

In my select I use sum to count various things.  Since the summing is done on records grouped by X, one row is returned with sum results for the entire group.

My question is can you do this with strings?  The different sums that I calculate are based on values within row. In these rows are text values I would like to collect in one final concatenated string.

I'm looking for something like sum_string(thistextvalue).

Thank you.

(I would have used a mysql-beginner tag but there isn't one.  I usually try to identify myself as a beginner - but some really smart guy edits it out.)

Comment: Try [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word) FROM table GROUP BY X
```

Comment: 100%.  Thank you.  You can even put logic in there!

Comment: Note that the variable `@@group_concat_max_len` limits the size of the resulting string to a fairly small size by default.  You will probably want to change this, to avoid truncation the resulting strings.  Temporarily, you can max it out and remove any limit for your current seasion with `SET @@group_concat_max_len = ~0;` which sets it to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF bytes. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Example from the docs:

> ```
>  SELECT student_name,
>      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
>                ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
>      FROM student
>      GROUP BY student_name;
> ```